# C char array in position independent code not in contiguous memory

Tags: c

I am learning how position independent code works and came across a project in Github called [ShellcodeStdio](https://github.com/jackullrich/ShellcodeStdio/tree/master) that turns C code into PIC. After building the example I looked at the output bytes that get saved to the bin file. One thing that caught my attention was the strings are not in same order as in the code. For example the code opens a message box and prints `Hello World`. When looking through the 400 bytes of output I do not see the string in a contiguous space of memory. Instead I see bytes that are what appear to be building the string.

```
0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0xC7, 0x45, 0xF4, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0xC7, 0x45, 0xF8, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x00
H     e     l     l     ?     E     ?     o           W     o     ?     E     ?     r     l     d     \0
```

After putting the bytes into a disassembler I can see that it is moving 4 bytes at a time on the stack to build the string.

The project was built using the following flags in Visual Studio:

```
C/C++ -> Optimization -> /O1, /Ob2, /Oi, /Os, /Oy-, /GL
C/C++ -> Code Generation -> /MT, /GS-, /Gy
Linker -> General -> /INCREMENTAL:NO
```

Is it possible to have the string be contiguous? My goal was to modify the bytes that were produced and change the text without having to change the text in the project and recompile.

Comment: Instead of depending on the strings being in the executable in some order you *expect*, which is probably an unfounded expectation, why not have an external data file you read in? Some old-school programming techniques involve declaring an arbitrarily fixed sized "scratch" buffer that you can frame using some kind of unique identifier, and manipulate after the executable is compiled, using it as a sort of writable data segment. It'd be better to explain your goal first, though. With code signing this technique is largely obsolete.

Comment: Can you please show us a [mre]? In the question itself, to make it self-contained.

Comment: An array cannot be non-contiguous. It's against the law. What you see in the binary is not an array, it is executable code.

Comment: Not enough info to tell. The array will be continuous in memory, but how you get that into your binary file is likely where the issue arises.